# How do I allow access to folders I mistakenly over secured in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

I stupidly denied access to my user folder for the administrator group, and now I can't fix the problem.

I set the Administrators and HomeUsers groups' permissions on my Account's user folder to Deny for Full Control (Which in turn set everything to deny). There was a dialog box telling me Deny takes precedence, but I didn't realize the implications at the time.

A regular administrator account doesn't work to fix the problem because they're automatically in the administrator group. I know I didn't block the SYSTEM user, but I haven't found any information on the internet to let me use that.

For posterity: I was trying to prevent my XP computer from getting access to those folders, but that's a different question entirely.

Comment: What did you do exactly.  Knowing this information can help determine what you need to do to reverse it.

Comment: I assume a System Restore didn't help?

Comment: You won't be able to apply the previous rights exactly, unless you have a backup to restore from. That said, an administrator can always take ownership of a directory, and then alter the permissions on the objects therein.

Comment: I set the Administrators and HomeUsers groups' permissions on my user folder to Deny for Full Control (Which in turn set _everything_ to deny). There was a dialog box telling me Deny takes precedence, but I didn't realize the implications at the time. I don't even know if I have System Restore working, but I'm pretty sure I turned it off (tiny hard drive).

Comment: Does using [the hidden Admin account](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/) work? Just taking a stab...

Comment: I'm trying the Hidden Admin account right now. It seems to be working, but is failing to apply the new (sane) security settings to subfolders.

Comment: Try going to Security tab > Advanced (at bottom) > Change Permissions >  Administrators > tick `Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object` (at bottom) > Edit > Full Control

Comment: I'm getting an Access Denied dialog box with Ok and Cancel buttons for some files and folders, but other files and folders are getting their permissions changed just fine. I'll go through one pass spamming Ok, and hope things get better. I'm not sure how long that will take because there's a lot of files.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to try that unfortunately! Also, to ping other users, please start your comment with an `@` followed by the person’s username (with no spaces). For example, to ping you, I would use `@Mengmoshu` (for more information, please see [How do comments replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work))

Comment: Hmm I remember doing this once, and I remember it was a total pain in the neck. I remember I had to untick something like "inherit permissions from parent" to make this pain go away for my folders. That might be what you need.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Looks like your advice to use the Hidden Admin account worked. You should make an Answer out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [Hidden Administrator Account](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/) (slightly higher privileges than the normal admin):

- Open an elevated command prompt (Start menu > cmd > right click > run as admin)
- Run this: `net user administrator /active:yes`
- Logout
- Login via the new account
- Go to your blocked folder
- Right click the folder > Properties
- Go to the `Security` tab > `Advanced` (at bottom) > `Change Permissions` > `Administrators` > tick `Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object` (at bottom) > `Edit` > tick `Full Control`

It might take a bit of manual labour to get this fully working - but it works!

Remember to disable the Hidden Admin account afterwards (for security)! - run this command: `net user administrator /active:no`